# how to get transactions on a database for a specific time

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu

I want to get the users from a postgresql database where users activity is not seen for a specific period of time etc. (Basically I am trying to get which users who are not using the application at all)

For example the following SQL query is for users not using for the last 30 days:

```sql
SELECT distinct on (username) username, started_at
FROM projects_user JOIN projects_synclog
ON projects_user.id = projects_synclog.user_id
WHERE started_at BETWEEN '2019-08-15' AND '2019-09-15' 
ORDER BY username, started_at DESC
```

In this query it is showing all the users which means for example a user may have logged in a month ago for once and again the same user has logged in 2 days ago. In this case, the user is still active, which I don't want to be listed out.

I have been trying this for countless hours. I searched for solutions a lot in here and other forums listed in google.

I would highly appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want aggregation and `having`.  This answers the question in the title:

```
SELECT pu.username, max(sl.started_at)
FROM projects_user pu LEFT JOIN
     projects_synclog sl
     ON pu.id = sl.user_id
GROUP BY pu.username
HAVING MAX(sl.started_at) IS NULL OR
       MAX(sl.started_at) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 DAY'
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Thanks for the solution. It really works great. However what I was looking for is whose last sync was or last used was (started_at) between this date and this date. Like who stopped using from last Monday till today. It would be great if I have the solution for this.

Comment: @Jay . . . You would just modify the `HAVING` clause to have the dates that you care about.

Comment: Is it like, HAVING MAX(started_at) BETWEEN this_date AND this_date

Comment: @Jay This solution by Gordon is probably what you need. By using LEFT JOIN instead of just JOIN it also includes users who have never synced, or that synced so long ago that you don't have sync information about them. If you have a created/signup-date in project_users that could be used to exclude users created during the last week. You could put `WHERE started_at IS NULL OR started_at BETWEEN '2019-08-15' AND '2019-09-15'` before `GROUP BY` if you want to limit how much sync data you want to process.

Comment: @Jay . . . Yes, if you want `BETWEEN`.  However, the phrasing of your question suggests that you want users whose activity is older than a certain date, which is why the answer has `<`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks a lot for this help. It prefectly works as I wanted.

Comment: For others seeking for the same help, I changed the last line of Gordon's answer to 'HAVING MAX(sl.started_at) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 'x DAY' AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 'y DAY''